# How can I "catch" action edit in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I want to create a new module that save history of a record when someone edit it but doesn't find out any documents regards how to catch an edit action. Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: I saw this file but it 's so confused to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to use the models in the addons store, You can create a new class inherit from models.Model and overrid the create and write method to save audit in another model and create new Model that inherit the new model not the models.Model class this when ever a create or write is happen it will call the create and write of the parent class not the create

Comment: Your words make me so embarrassed but I got your ideals, let me try

Answer (score 1):

There are few modules in app store which provide that functionality.

[Audit Trail](https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/smile_audit/)

[Audit Log](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/auditlog/)

One blog is there, how to use audit trail in odoo prepared by Mayur maherswari.

[Audit Trail in OpenERP - (Odoo)](http://maheshwarimayur.blogspot.in/2013/02/audit-trail-in-openerp.html)

Comment: tks, I 'll research module Audit Log to find out how to handle action